# Programming language for LinkedIn App Development

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I want to develop an application using LinkedIn but confused over which programming language I should pick. Linkedin supports REST & JS APIs and there is some sample code given in PHP & Ruby. I have good command on C/C++ and basic knowledge of JS and PHP. I want to know how should I start as I didn't find Linkedin documentation very elaborate. Which language is preferred for this kind of development and how much popular that is in community to gather future support?

Please share your views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with PHP with a combination of Ruby, AJAX and JS. but once you get started you'll advance sooner than you had thought.

Comment: thanks, more comments please !!!